# How many hamilton paths can a non-hamiltonian graph have?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

What is the maximum number of hamilton paths a graph with $n$ vertices can have
 without having a hamiton cycle ?

If my turbo pascal program works well, the first few values for $3,4,...$ vertices are $2,4,12,48,240$ , which approves the conjecture that $2(n-2)!$ is the maximum.

Comment: At least $(n-2)!$

Comment: At least $2(n-2)!$, since it seems you are counting directed paths.  Take the complete graph on $n-1$ vertices and adjoin one vertex $v$ by a single edge.  All Hamilton paths must start or end with $v$ together with the single neighbour of $v$, but the remaining $n-2$ vertices can be visited in arbitrary order.

Comment: It seems that $2(n-2)!$ is indeed the maximum. If directed paths are not counted, the number would be $(n-2)!$